# Import "rest_framework" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was installing a django Rest Framework for my project. I installed this with
`pip install djangorestframework` it worked perfectly fine, then i add a `rest_framework` line into INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py. And now at this point I want to import Response from rest_framework in views.py but it shows:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Response' from 'rest_framework'`
It looks like it's not installed I guess, but it is ... I checked even a version of rest_framework from the console and it shows everything.

Do you have any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, so I am posting it for people who had the same problem. Just do Ctrl+Shift+P if you are using VSC and then change the version of intepreter - it worked for me.

Comment: What version of the interpreter were you experiencing problems in?  What version did you switch it to?

Answer (score 0):

This simply worked for me.
I had to use **pip3** but I still think **pip** would have worked too.

First, I deactivated my environment and upgraded pip

> `source env/bin/deactivate`

> `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

I activated my environment again, then installed Django and Django REST framework

> `pip3 install django`

> `pip3 install djangorestframework`

After that, you can import Response from rest_framework in views.py

The steps worked out for me.